# Ziggy Router Defaulting to Query String

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, url-routing, inertiajs, ziggy

I am attempting to access the route "localhost:8000/contact/edit/{contact}

in my vue file I am attempting it with

```
<Link :href="route('contact.edit', {contact:contact.id})">Edit Contact</Link>
```

Route in web.php

```
    Route::prefix('contact')->group(function() {
        Route::post('/', [ContactController::class, 'store'])->name('contact.store');
        Route::get('/create/{customer}', [ContactController::class, 'create'])->name('contact.create');
        Route::get('/edit/{contact}', [ContactController::class, 'edit'])->name('contact.edit');
    });
```

Controller:

```
    public function edit(Contact $contact) {
        dd($contact);
    }
```

When doing things this way, I get the error that the contact parameter is required:

```
Error: Ziggy error: 'contact' parameter is required for route 'contact.edit'.
```

Removing the parameter requirement shows that Ziggy is trying to go here:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/contact/edit?contact=88
```

Why would Ziggy default to using a query string on a routine route request? I have overcome this by just writing the url out, but No one on my team can figure out why it is acting this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was working on this problem with OG and we figured out that for some reason the ID is coming out as a string.

The current solution we have come up with is

```html
<a :href='route("contact.test", { contact: parseInt(contact.id) })'>Test</a>
```

The parseInt causes Ziggy to stop throwing a fit. We are going down the path to figure out why our ID is coming out as a string.

Comment: As crazy as this sounds, this solved the issue. Even checking with typeOf, contact.id is a number before and after using parseInt().

Comment: We are still baffled by the need for parseInt()

Comment: Oh. I'm using TypeScript, so it never occurred to me that the id is not a number! Clever.

Comment: The crazy thing is that the id is a number. If we throw typeof on the id it says its a number. The DB is set to big int so there is not much a reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

### When insert variable after "?"

`Ziggy` inserts any undefined parameter in the URL into the URL Query section.

For example, based on your `/contact/edit/{contact}` URL, if I asked it for:

```js
route("contact.edit", { contact: 88, username: "Test" })
```

this would be the result: `/contact/edit/88?username=test`, because username was not part of the original URL.

The error causing Ziggy to put contact in the Query section for you could be that you didn't update the JS file containing the routes generated by Ziggy after updating Laravel's web.php file:

**`php artisan ziggy:generate`**.

### When get error: "'xy' parameter is required"

When you omit a required parameter from the route() function, Ziggy will throw an error on the console and won't generate a URL.

The link provided here is correctly constructed and the route declaration is correct. The issue may have been caused by not updating your website when you added `, { contact: contact.id }` to the `route()` function.

Additionally, if you didn't manipulate the route() function and are using the latest version, it should work correctly.

Comment: I did not know about it throwing things into the URL query section if they are not asked for, that is good to know. 

I used the ziggy:generate command and still get the same error.

hard coding in a number gives me the correct info, and I am able to display the id using {{ contact.id}} in other spots, but when I use it conjunction with the route() function it displays nothing.

Strangely, when I use contact.id in the route function as an unrequested query string, the id will show up.